# Cannot SELECT data from oracle table with hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I created a simple spring mvc web app with `hibernate` and `mysql` (Everything worked well). Then, I changed `mysql` to `oracle`. After first run of the application, (connected to oracle database) tables, corresponding to the entity models defined in my application, were created.   I added one country and one user to `COUNTRY` and `MYAPPUSER` tables from `SQL DEVELOPER`. Now, I am trying to get a user from `MYAPPUSER` table but I am getting null instead of user, which exists.

This is User entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "myAppUser")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "id_Sequence")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "id_Sequence", sequenceName = "ID_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "Id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "FirstName")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "LastName")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "Username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "Password")
    private String password;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private List<UserSubject> userSubjects;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "country_id", nullable = false)
    private Country country;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private List<Test> testList;

    //and getters and setters

}
```

This is code while debugging:

[image]

In sql developer:

[image]

this is generated sql by hibernate:

[image]

I am interested in why user is null after selecting data and why question marks are in place of `user1` and `123` in generated sql?

I think this effect is specific to oracle, because I had not such problem with MySQL database.

P.S Exceptions aren't thrown....

Comment: Is is actually executing a query? *Getting null* and *not getting any result* are two different things. I don't know Java though.

Comment: Is there any way to determine if query was executed or not in oracle?

Comment: You might query `v$open_cursor` for the connected session ID. Can Hibernate not tell you what it did?

Comment: > question marks are in place of user1 and 123 in generated sql? < Hibernate automatically converts your query in a Prepared Statement and '?' are placeholders for variables

Comment: Silly question, perhaps: did you commit the changes in SQL Developer?

Comment: @LukeWoodward what do you mean in commiting changes? Tables in database correspond to the models in application.

Comment: By committing the changes, I mean either running a `COMMIT` statement in SQL Developer or clicking the button with a tick in front of a cylinder (sixth one from either side in your SQL Developer image).  It looks like you entered the data using SQL Developer; until you commit, you will only be able to see this data using the same connection you used to insert it.  Apologies if you've already done this, but we do have questions on Stack Overflow much like yours where it turns out the person asking hadn't committed the changes in one connection so couldn't see them from another.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I am new to oracle and I haven't seen commit in other databases.. :)

Comment: Sorry, it's not entirely clear from your comment whether you've now solved your problem.  Did you commit in SQL Developer and did your Spring MVC web app then start showing the user?

Comment: Yes, I solved. Write answer and I will mark it as correct..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments the solution was to commit in SQL Developer.